# Subset of $\Bbb R$ that doesn’t satisfy $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\mu((E+\epsilon)\backslash E)=0$

Tags: lebesgue-measure

There is a subset $E$ of $\Bbb R$ that doesn’t satisfy $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\mu((E+\epsilon)\backslash E)=0$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I came up with $\Bbb R\backslash \Bbb Q$ and $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}[n,n+{1\over n}]$ but they don’t seem to work. I know that it has to have infinite measure...

Comment: @SangchulLee and that has measure $>0$ when $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Wow that’s my bad

Comment: I think that your second example will also work, but here is another example: Let $E = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} [2n-1,2n]$. Then for $0 < \epsilon < 1$, we have $(E+\epsilon)\setminus E = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} (2n, 2n+\epsilon]$.